# Payment Gateway Integration in load balancing

Tags: asp.net

I am planning to integrate a payment gateway in one of our websites but that particular website is already been configured as an load balancing mode. My question is if I try making the payment from X server and another one from Y server, the X and Y server are configured to a single website in load balancing, what happens when the payments merchant returns with the transaction details? Will it be directed to the Server X or Server Y?

Kindly help me out

regards
Kabs

Answer (score 0):

Your load balancer should support sticky sessions.  This means that as long as "I" am accessing Server X, all of my requests and responses will stay with Server X.

If your load balancer does not support sticky sessions, then I would request that they be turned on.